# Upload de projeto NetBeans no GitHub

Tags: netbeans, github

Nunca tive experiência com o GitHub, fiz uma biblioteca simples de `php` e queria publicar ela no Git pela IDE `NetBeans`, andei pesquisando, achei algo parecido, mas não consegui fazer o upload, alguém sabe como funciona?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A equipe do `NetBeans` me auxiliou a resolver esse problema, vamos ao passo á passo:

- Entre na conta do [GitHub](https://github.com).
- Crie um `Novo Repositório`.
- Ao criar será lhe passado links `https` ou `ssh` para fazer o `upload` dos arquivos, parecidos com esse:

  https://github.com/Leonardo-Souza/MinPDO.git
- No `NetBeans`, abra o projeto que deseja, na aba `Projetos` clique no nome do mesmo com o `botão direito` e entre no menu `Controle de Versão / Inicializar Repositório Git`, apenas `Avance`.
- Selecione no menu `Janelas` a `Saída` (ou pressione `Ctrl + 4`), um console será aberto, veja se não há nenhum erro.
- Volte na aba `Projetos` e agora novamente com o botão direito vá para `Git / Fazer Commit`, após isso pressione o botão `Fazer Commit` e verifique no console se a mensagem de conclusão foi exibida.
- Verifique se alguns arquivos do ser projeto possui a descrição `Passed`, se sim continue, se não espere um pouco ou refaça os passos anteriores.
- Mais uma vez na aba `Projetos`, agora no menu `Git / Remoto / Expandir`, selecione o radio box `Especificar a Localização do Repositório Git`, no input, cole o link `https` que o `GitHub` te deu, adicione suas credenciais de login e pressione `Próximo`.
- Na próxima tela marque a opção `master -> master` e clique em `Próximo`, depois em `Finalizar`.
- Cole o link `https` no navegador e veja seus arquivos já no repositório.

Answer (score 0):

Uma dúvida, sempre que eu precisar atualizar o código no repositório preciso fazer o passo 8 "*no menu Git / Remoto / Expandir, selecione o radio box Especificar a Localização do Repositório Git, no input, cole o link https que o GitHub te deu, adicione suas credenciais de login e pressione Próximo*"? Existe alguma forma de fazer atualização de forma automática?