# Como que eu faço para abrir um projeto do GitHub no netbeans?

Tags: github, netbeans

Tenho um trabalho a fazer em grupo, foi criado um projeto no Github para baixarmos e trabalharmos nele, porém não consigo abrir o projeto no Netbeans para alterar e fazer comits.

OBS: Eu não quero criar um projeto e mandar para o github e sim baixar um projeto de lá e abrir no netbeans ou clonar.

alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Upload de projeto NetBeans no GitHub](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105576/upload-de-projeto-netbeans-no-github)

Comment: Leu a resposta do link que indiquei? Ela explica como importar pro netbeants do github.